# Show how many total files in sharepoint by file type?

Tags: search-results, content, crawl

ive noticed our crawl DB is crawling 65000 files, i was wondering how i can get a break down of these files by content type?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your SharePoint version Search may be able to give you that.

If you're using 2010 with FAST or 2013 then refiners are accurate so you can:

Setup a Search page with refiner on the property you want counts for (with counts enabled)

Do a search which returns everything you're interested in can be:

"IsDocument:1" for documents
"write>1900-01-01" for everything